# how to convert a parameter value in php

Tags: php

How can I convert a value that I get in `datepicker` in php.........
I tried the code below.

I tried passing the value into `$from_date` to $date and then convert the `$date` but the output is the current date, not the parameter `datepicker`.......

Here is the output:

[image]

And my code:

```
$from_date = $_POST["from_date"];
$date = $from_date; 
$date = date('F d y'); 
echo $date
```

Comment: You need to provide a datestamp to the date() function otherwise it will give the value of time() ie the current time. Read the PHP manual on date().  "Returns a string formatted according to the given format string using the given integer timestamp or the current time if no timestamp is given. In other words, timestamp is optional and defaults to the value of time()"

Comment: any idea how to get the parameter value @bcperth

Comment: What is the format of  $_POST["from_date"]? ie what does the datepicker return?

Comment: @bcperth thanks for replaying its YEAR - MONTH - AND DAY

Comment: Please echo it and update your question showing the output exactly. Also show the exact format you want to convert it to. Then we can find the right way to re-format as you need.

Answer (score 0):

does this work as expected?

```
$from_date = $_POST["from_date"];
$date = date('F d y', $from_date); 
echo $date;
```

Comment: thanks for replaying mr @Jimmix but i have some error  A non well formed numeric value encountered

Comment: put `var_dump($from_date);` between first and second line of my code and put in comment what it prints